# PhantomJS - Upload file to facebook

Tags: facebook, upload, phantomjs, web-crawler

I'm trying to use PhantomJS 2.1.1 to update my profile picture on facebook. I'm able to log in, and navigate to the page where I should upload the picture, but **page.uploadFile** is just not working.

The last screenshot (page.render('end.png')) shows facebook alert **"Please choose file to upload"** confirming that **page.uploadFile** didn't work.

Any idea on how I can achieve this?

[upload_page2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZrqu.png)

[end.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRCiT.png)

```
var args = require('system').args;
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://m.facebook.com', function(status){

    if(status === "success"){
        setTimeout(function(){
            page.evaluate(function (args) {
                 document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value = args[1]; 
                 document.getElementsByName("pass")[0].value = args[2]; 
                 document.getElementById("loginbutton").click();
            }, args);    
         }, 2000);

         setTimeout(function(){
              page.render('logged.png');
              page.open('https://m.facebook.com/photos/upload/?profile_pic&upload_source=profile_pic_upload&profile_pic_source=tagged_photos_page', function(status){
              });
         }, 4000);

         setTimeout(function(){
              page.render('upload_page1.png');
              page.uploadFile('input[name=file1]', 'http://proprofs-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/images/games/user_images/misc/4288844624.png');   
         }, 6000);


         setTimeout(function(){
             page.render('upload_page2.png');
             page.evaluate(function (args) {
                 var a = document.querySelectorAll('[type="submit"]'); 
                 a[0].click();
             }, args);   
          }, 10000);



    } else {
        console.log("Error opening url \"" + page.reason_url + "\": " + page.reason);
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        page.render('end.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 15000);

});
```

Comment: It seems, you can't do that by using an image from the url, uploading only from your PC is allowed.

Comment: Based on what pls? Facebook accepts external URL when I follow the same steps on my browser.

Comment: [i can't do it by using FireFox, OS Linux Debian 8.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_tqnSHhFPBncFZxWi1PNHVtWDA/view)

Comment: Oh.. you are correct. I've tried with a local image and it is working now. (I tried before but I made a typo, so didn't work - hours spent on that). Thank you!